# Huge transaction log with SQL Server database in simple recovery mode

Tags: sql-server

I have a fairly large SQL Server database that is using SIMPLE recovery mode. We don't really have a need for up to the second recovery so i'd prefer we stay with this mode.

For some reason the transaction log for this database is massive (410 GB) with 99% of the space unallocated.

I've tried to shrink the file using ( DBCC SHRINKFILE (MyDatabase_log, 20000) )but it doesn't seem to work.

Anyone have any tips on why a SIMPLE recovery mode database would have such a huge file? I'd really like to get it shrunk way down.

Comment: Last time I checked, the default shrink units were in GB. So what you declared there might have been `20000 GB`, which would not have any effect :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It means you once had a single transaction that lasted for so long that it forced the log to grow 410GB. The log cannot be reused if there is an active transaction since the rollback information cannot be erased. Such an example would be if someone open an SSMS query, starts a transaction, updates a record and then goes in vacation. The transaction will be active and force the log to grow until is eventually committed or rolled back. When the transaction eventually ends the used space can finally be reclaimed, leaving a huge empty log file.

Another scenario is if you had about 200GB of data updated in a single transaction. The log will store the before and after images of the changes thus consuming twice the space, and it cannot be reused, again because is all one single transaction.

**Update**

I neglected to mention Replication that is also a factor that can prevent log truncation. And so is Mirroring, an distributed transaction (technically that is the same as an 'active transaction', but the DTC implication makes it a distinct case). The complete list and explanations is at [Factors That Can Delay Log Truncation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345414.aspx).

Comment: It wouldn't show as unallocated space if it were mid-rollback/transaction, would it?

Comment: Thanks! This sounds very possible. Do you know what can be done to remove the log if it's in this locked state?

Comment: If it shows as unallocated the space must be already claimed back by the SIMPLE recovery mode. Does the `log_reuse_wait_desc` column of sys.databases for the database in question says `NOTHING` or not?

Comment: CHECKPOINT
NOTHING
ACTIVE_TRANSACTION
NOTHING
REPLICATION
NOTHING
NOTHING
NOTHING

Comment: @Remus: That's what I thought. Since 99% of his space is unallocated, I figured there wasn't a hanging transaction. He's obviously confirmed that, though :)

Comment: @Eric can you restrict that only to the database of interest, not your entire server? There is at least one `REPLICATION` entry, do you have replication off the database in question?

Comment: @Eric (OP) from the reply to no_one is clear you have replication from the database. Replication is another one of them log shrink/reuse restriction factors. You need all your subscribers to catch up, the server keeps track of who has received what in replication. If a subscriber is behind, it will cause the log to grow, same as an active transaction.

Comment: I see. I bet this is the problem since I'm seeing lots of errors in my replication subscriber database. I'll try to turn off replication and see if that allows me to shrink the file.

Comment: @Remus: I may have misinterpreted your explanation but I thought Replication would only delay truncation of the Publishers transaction log if the transaction had not been committed to the Distributor database (as opposed to the Subscriber)?

Comment: Yep. Turning off replication has now allowed me to shrink the log using NOTRUNCATE. Thanks Eric & Remus!

Comment: @John: I think you are right. I'm not an expert in Replication, but it makes sense that only the distributor needs to read the log for transaction based replication, not each subscriber.

Comment: @Remus: Hmmm I wonder then if the posters distribution database was the root cause, perhaps a space issue there...

Comment: @John: yes, replication can grow the log as such if the distributor is not reading the log: either the agents don't run (schedule is busted usually due to operator intervention) or they run but can't connect to the publisher.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing an argument in [`dbcc shrinkfile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx):

```
dbcc shrinkfile (MyDatabase_log, 20000, TRUNCATEONLY)
```

`NOTRUNCATE` is the default, which moves allocated blocks to the beginning of unallocated space. `TRUNCATEONLY` removes the unallocated space. So if you do a `NOTRUNCATE` followed by a `TRUNCATEONLY`, you get one slimmed down log.

Comment: I did try that. It didn't change anything. I did add a second log file to get the batabase back online when the space ran out. Maybe that's part of it?

Comment: @Eric (Good name, btw): Make sure then, that you're shrinking the right log. If you have two log files, you'll need to shrink both independently. Check in the Files section of the database properties for what they're called. I think the default is `MyDatabase_log_1`, but I'm going off the top of my head.

Comment: The documentation I read said that the default units were in GB, not MB, which may be the underlying reason why this did not work. This may vary between versions of SQL Server - I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

If you have only one mdf file and one log file, perhaps the simplest way will be to detach the database, rename the log and reattach the database. SQL Server will create a new log file. After that your huge log file can be safely deleted.

This though will not work if you have multiple data files.

Comment: Thanks. I did try this but it wouldn't let me detach because the database acts as a replication publisher.

Comment: This worked great, I could not get the damn thing to shrink all the DBCC SHRINKFILEs in the world would not budge.  Anyway it was just a test DB not production, so I tried this.  Works great just need to remove the "re-attach" .ldf file part as obviously it is not there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Replication Publisher? Could this be the reason for the huge transaction log?

Answer (score 1):

As said in other responses, **Active Transactions** and **Replications** are typical causes for this problem.
Another one, less visible, is **Change Data Capture** (CDC).

I had a similar problem recently and the procedure which allowed me to free the log was as follow:

- Disable CDC: `EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_db`
- Create a publication on an arbitrary table within the database in question
- Delete this/all publication(s).  `EXEC sp_removedbreplication 'my_db'`  is a convenient way to do so.
- Shrink the log as desired

I'm unsure why the **creation/deletion of this *dummy/never-used* publication was necessary** but it was so.  Tentatively the database may have had previous publications which were not disposed of properly (it is said to happen frequently with databases restored from a previous backup).

Another useful diagnostic idiom is to check the ***log_reuse_wait_desc*** in sys.databases for the offending database.  This field read `REPLICATION` until I completed the above procedure.

```
SELECT log_reuse_wait_desc, * FROM sys.databases where name = 'my_db'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a local dev db and could only get it to shrink after running `CHECKPOINT` on the db a few times, not sure what got it in that locked state to begin with.