# How can I solve whatever is causing SQL Server to throw "The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full due to 'NOTHING'"?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlexception, transaction-log, tempdb

SQL Server complains that it is full of nothing, which is, I guess, better than being full of some other things. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421370/the-transaction-log-for-database-databasename-is-full) has some very interesting answers, especially the one by Steven.

However, after running the script he provided, rather than seeing TRANSACTION or BACKUP as the entries in the log_reuse_wait_description column, I see only "NOTHING" and "CHECKPOINT" Every "state_desc" value is "ONLINE" and every "recovery_model_desc" is "SIMPLE". All of the "Last FULL Backup" vals are the same, too - 10/31/2014 - almost a year-and-a-half ago.

I am no DBAdmin by a long stretch, so have no idea what these things mean, or most importantly, how to prevent the err msg from occurring.

Is there anything I can do from the C# side to prevent this "full of nothing" error from occurring?

The entire err msg is:

> *Date: 3/7/2016 2:24:45 PM Message: Monday, March 07, 2016: Exception message: The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full due to
>   'NOTHING'.  Exception Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider Exception
>   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)    at
>   ReportRunner.SharedCode.SQLDBHelper.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(String
>   sql, CommandType cmdType, SqlParameter[] parameters)*

So the code that is mine that is referenced in that msg is ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(), which is:

```
public static DataTable ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(string connectionStr, string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = EXTENDED_TIMEOUT;
        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
        }

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sqlex.Errors.Count; i++)
            {
                var sqlexDetail = String.Format("From ExecuteDataSet(), SQL Exception #{0}{1}Source: {2}{1}Number: {3}{1}State: {4}{1}Class: {5}{1}Server: {6}{1}Message: {7}{1}Procedure: {8}{1}LineNumber: {9}",
                    i + 1, // Users might get the fantods if they saw #0
                    Environment.NewLine,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Source,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Number,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].State,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Class,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Server,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Message,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].Procedure,
                    sqlex.Errors[i].LineNumber);
                ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.HandleException(sqlex);
            }
            return null; // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883125/how-can-i-defensively-code-against-randomly-referencing-table-0-and-null-value?noredirect=1#comment55530765_33883125
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.HandleException(ex);
            return null;
        }
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

So is there anything I can add to this code to alleviate or even eliminate the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Huge transaction log with SQL Server database in simple recovery mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195867/huge-transaction-log-with-sql-server-database-in-simple-recovery-mode)

Comment: I solved it by breaking up my database retrieval operations into two "passes"; for the details, see my auto-answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022999/what-can-i-do-to-programmatically-prevent-or-limit-resource-contentions